# Mixing PHP Value and VueJS values

Tags: vue.js

Im workign on a small project and Im using VUEJS and PHP backed onto Wordpress.

```
<div v-if="ent.Account === 'username' " v-for="ent in leaders">
hey there {{ ent.Name }} welcome back!
</div>
```

Im wanting the "username" to be equal to the current logged in user from wordpress

```
<?php $current_user->user_login ?>
```

Comment: try `ent.Account === '<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>'`

Answer (score 0):

VueJS is a client-side-only library, while PHP is server-side. You cannot mix things directly, but since you're using wordpress you can "localize" your javascript.

If you're using tools like webpack or browserify, then you should localize your bundled app.js and/or chunk-vendor.js, otherwise you can localize vue.js itself directly, like this (assuming you're working with a theme)

In your functions.php, write

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_js_script_handle',
        get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/app.js', // <<---- your Vue bundled code
        array(),
        false,
        true // <<--- Enqueue in footer
    );

    /**
     * Add initial data to your Vue JS object.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    $data = array(
        'currentWpUser' => wp_get_current_user()->user_login,
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_js_script_handle', 'PhpDataObject', $data ); // <<--- localize your script

}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```

and  in your client-side javascript consume your PHP generated data like this (assuming you're using tools like vue-cli or vueify)

```
<div id="app">
    <p>hey there {{ currentWpUser }} welcome back!</p>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentWpUser: PhpDataObject.currentWpUser
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div v-if="ent.Account === '<?php $current_user->user_login ?>' " v-for="ent in leaders">
hey there {{ ent.Name }} welcome back!
</div>
```